# Programmatically constructing the workbook in Tableau

Tags: python, mysql, tableau-api, business-intelligence

I am developing an ETL tool in python. The code generates some data which is then stored in MySQL database. I want to view this data in Tableau (or for that matter any BI visualization tool). For that I have to manually drag and drop the tables into workbook and specify join conditions.

My current workbook looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiTRd.png).
Now as the number of tables increases this task becomes cumbersome to do manually. Is it possible to tell the names of the tables and join conditions programmatically. The construction of the sheet/graphs can be done manually. Only the table specification is to be automated since its hectic and error prone.

My research:

1. I came across an option **Convert to custom SQL** in which gives the following output. This is the exact thing I want to tell tableau. But there is no import option of such format.

   > SELECT
   >   `ship_line`.`ship_lineid` AS `ship_lineid`,
   >   `ship_line`.`name` AS `name`,
   >   `ship_line`.`product_dcid` AS `product_dcid`,
   >   `ship_line`.`shipmentid` AS `shipmentid`,
   >   `ship_line`.`sl_act_gi_dte` AS `sl_act_gi_dte`,
   >   ...
   >   ...
   >   FROM `ship_line`
   >   INNER JOIN `product_dc` ON (`ship_line`.`_product_dcid` = `product_dc`.`_product_dcid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `shipment` ON (`ship_line`.`_shipmentid` = `shipment`.`_shipmentid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `ship_to` ON (`shipment`.`_ship_toid` = `ship_to`.`_ship_toid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `ship_from` ON (`shipment`.`_ship_fromid` = `ship_from`.`_ship_fromid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `dc` ON (`shipment`.`_dcid` = `dc`.`_dcid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `carrier` ON (`shipment`.`_carrierid` = `carrier`.`_carrierid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `product` ON (`product_dc`.`_productid` = `product`.`_productid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `opco` ON (`product`.`_opcoid` = `opco`.`_opcoid`)
   >   INNER JOIN `key_customer` ON (`ship_to`.`_key_customerid` = `key_customer`.`_key_customerid`)
2. We can export the workbook to **.twb** or **.twbx** file. This file contains all the information regarding the workbook. The **.twb** file is human readable. I can look into creating this file by a script and import it to view the workbook. But I don't really understand the semantics of tags used in it. Is there any documentation for this format.

Can someone provide a way to do this or suggest some other BI/visualization tool that can achieve this.

Comment: I think you are in "Not supported/recommended by Tableau" territory here. I don't think you will get documentation on tags used in Tableau's workbook.  I would recommend using a 'published' data source on tableau server, which has all the tables and join conditions updated manually. All your workbooks can simply used this data-source. Any changes for new tables/joins then would have to be done only at a single place (the data source) instead of all the individual workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the tableau data extract API. Might be called the tableau SDK now.

Best approach is generate a tableau data extract (tdx file) programmatically and connect your hand constructed workbook (twb file) to it. Then when you regenerate the extract, your workbook automatically sees the changes